# USB microphone locks up - how to fix?

Tags: usb, audio, input-device, reset

The USB microphone occasionally gets locked up such that nothing can use it.

The utility `arecord` describes it as follows:

```
card 1: Device [DYNEX USB MIC Device], device 0:USB Audio [USB Audio]
    Subdevices: 1/1
    Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

When the microphone stops working, `arecord` gives diagnostics like this:

```
> arecord -D plughw:1,0 > recording.wav
Recording WAVE 'stdin' : Unsigned 8 bit, Rate 8000 Hz, Mono
arecord: set_params:1145: Unable to install hw_params:
ACCESS:  RW_INTERLEAVED
FORMAT:  U8
etc...
```

Unplugging and plugging the microphone fixes it, only because the current dip forces the RasPi to reboot! Not an ideal situation.

Is there a way to fix this from the command line or a C executable? I saw something using `ioctl(fd, USBDEVFS_RESET, 0)` but no idea which filename to open to correspond to device and not sure if that would work anyway.

Comment: Would a better power supply be an option? A powered hub?

Comment: It's already using its own dedicated power supply - "the best!". The dip is because the RasPi has a current limiter, so regardless of how good the power supply is, it will shut off when this microphone is plugged into it. So maybe the option should be getting a better microphone!

Comment: Use a separate USB hub with its own power supply. Then it wont reset.

Answer (score 1):

You could use lsof to see what process is locking the device

lsof | grep /dev/snd

for example, and maybe kill the offending process if there's a process locking it.

Comment: Doesn't show up in lsof, tried grepping *dev*, *snd*, *usb* and *pcm* not seeing anything.

Comment: `killall arecord` ?